# Leaflet map integration: Leaflet's CSS overriden by website's CSS-file?

Tags: html, css, leaflet

I want to add a Leaflet map to my Website. Unfortunately my own CSS file seems to override Leaflet's CSS-file on some elements.

The map's zoom buttons should look like this:

[image]

But they now look like this on my homepage:

[image]

I wonder if it is my own CSS file overriding the CSS from Leaflet. But how can I prevent this? Have a look at my `#content a`. Seems like the zoom buttons are interpreted as a link and so take the CSS properties from my file.

```css
body {
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 1000px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 700px;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 2.5em 0 2.5em;
 margin: 0;
}

#content p, ol, ul {
 font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
 color: #444444;
}

#content a:link, #content a:visited {
 color: #C09100;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#content a:hover, #content a:active {
 color: #C09100;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

#map {
 height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

strong {
 color: #444444;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
 color: #444444;
 font: 3em "Amatic SC";
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 color: #444444;
 font: 2em "Amatic SC";
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Link to Leaflet's CSS file: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
  <!-- My own CSS file: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rumkommenstyle.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/Leaflet.MakiMarkers.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js?v1.3.0"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="content">
      
      <div id="map">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var layer = new L.StamenTileLayer("watercolor");
          var map = new L.Map("map", {
            center: new L.LatLng(56.074207, -3.376634),
            zoom: 6
          });
          var icon = L.MakiMarkers.icon({
            icon: "marker",
            color: "#900",
            size: "m",
          });

          map.addLayer(layer);

          L.marker([56.074207, -3.376634], {
            icon: icon,
            title: 'Crossgates, Fife, Scotland',
            alt: 'Crossgates, Fife, Scotland',
          }).addTo(map);
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

(answer edited)

Short answer:

To get the black color on your zoom in/out buttons, you can add this to your css:

> .leaflet-bar > a:link {   color: black; }

Long answer:

You notice that your div with id="map" contains a script. When this script is run, it creates a div with class leaflet-bar in which the zoom buttons are actually links.

So, if you look at the tree of elements, you'll find that #content contains div.leaflet-bar which contains the zoom links.

So, which color should apply to the links ( #content a:link or .leaflet-bar a:link) ?

Colors of leaflet links are set in http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css

Comment: Thank you! I changed all the id's to classes but unfortunately that didn't solve my problem about the zoom buttons. I had to leave the "map" div as an id though, because otherwise it wouldn't be recognized by the script. Maybe that's the reason why?

Comment: I reproduced your problem and I can see that my answer does not solve it. I hove to find a valid explanation.

Comment: Thanks again for your explanation. As stated earlier I already changed all my other divs (except "map") to classes. So it's now `.content`, not `#content` anymore. I added `.leaflet-bar>a:link {color: #000; text-decoration: none;}` to my CSS but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: I am sorry this does not work for you (what browser are you using ? it works for me with Firefox and IE). Note that it can behave differently depending on the context (see https://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/hwmc0nmv/ where I did not need to use the >). Hopefully we will find a rational explanation.